# Getting a substring of a pointer

Tags: c++, string, pointers

I have a function that takes a pointer to a string as a parameter. I want to find the substring of that string, but I try to use use `*str.substr()` but it says I'm trying to call member function `substr()`and `str` isn't of class `std:string*` What do I do?

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
     string str;
     foo(&str);
}

void foo(string *str){
     string temp = *str.substring(int, int);
}
```

The above is the gyst of the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are falling fould of operator precedence rules, which means your code is read as

```
*(str.substring(int, int));
```

You can use the pointer de-reference operator `->`

```
str->substring(a, b);
```

or use parentheses to be explicit about what you want

```
(*str).substring(int, int);
```

The simpler solution, unless the argument can be null, is to pass a reference:

```
foo(const std::string& str){
     std::string temp = str.substring(a, b);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's due to [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence). The element selection  operator `.` has higher precedence than the dereference operator `*`, so the compiler actually sees it as

```
*(str.substr(...))
```

There are a few ways to solve this. The one I would recommend is to not use pointers, but references instead for the argument. Then you don't have to worry about dereferencing or possible null-pointers. And if you don't want to modify the original string then a constant reference.

Like

```
void foo(const std::string& str)
{
    // ...

    std::string temp = str.substr(...);

    // ...
}
```

Then call it without the address-of operator

```
std::string str = ...;
foo(str);
```